# I am using edmx to fetch data from database in C#.Net. Is there any way to fetch a single column without booting the entire object?

Tags: c#

I am using edmx to fetch data from database in C#.Net. For that, I have to boot the entire object. Is there any way to fetch a single column without booting the entire object?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Habib's answer, you do not have to create an anonymous type. You can just select the column you want:

```
var result = db.YourTable
    .Select(x => x.YourColumn)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) Using `select new` to select just one column from the table.

```
var result = from t in db.yourTable
             select new 
                { 
                 ID = t.ID
                };
```

The above query will give you an anonymous object containing just `ID` column from `yourtable`. You may also get multiple columns, or you may project the resultset to your custom type